# How to turn On and Off bluetooth visibility mode?

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I already turned on my bluetooth by running `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` command on terminal.I want to turn on my blutooth visibility mode also, so that only my device will get detected.All i have to do from command-line.

How to turn on and off Bluetooth's visibility mode in Ubuntu 14.04 from command-line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In BlueZ >= 5 command line control of a device can be done with [btmgmt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/btmgmt) tool:

```
sudo btmgmt
[mgmt]# help         # list commands
[mgmt]# info         # list device(s)
[mgmt]# select hciX  # select a known device by index X eg. hci0
[hci0]# discov yes   # make hci0 visible/discoverable
[hic0]# discov no    # make hci0 invisible
```

---

In older version of BlueZ we can control our Bluetooth device with the command line tool [hciconfig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/hciconfig.8.html).

To **enable visibility**:

```
sudo hciconfig hciX piscan
```

To **disable visibility**:

```
sudo hciconfig hciX noscan
```

Replace `hciX` with your device (usually `hci0`)

To query your Bluetooth device(s):

```
sudo hciconfig -a
```

Comment: perfect.Works dramastically :-)

Comment: @Takkat: For me, hci0 does not work. How to determine hciX?

Comment: @Curious: see edit - does this help?